colorscheme difference between distros
My team recently switched our main development platform from Ubuntu to Amazon Linux, and I noticed significant differences in the elflord colorscheme definition file (I didn't check any of the other schemes, but I assume they were different also.)
Why would this be?  Surely colorscheme definitions are independent of any particular distro?
The Ubuntu vim version is 8.2.2637.
The Amazon Linux vim version is 9.0.2153.

Could you tell us what is the version of Vim (i.e. the result of the :version Vim command) for both environments?

Could it be that the colors in the terminal (or emulator) are different to begin with? I am not sure if vim can access colors that are not defined there.

@VivianDeSmedt Updated with vim versions.  Thanks.

Vim has been actively maintained by a lot of people for decades and it keeps evolving from release to release. So, when it comes to particular features/behaviors, distros don't matter: Vim versions do and you didn't provide that info.
Case in point, we recently rewrote all the colorschemes bundled with Vim except default so it is highly likely that the Vim shipped with your Amazon Linux version is a newer version/build than the one shipped with your Ubuntu version. You can test it with the following command, in Vim:
:version

or this one, your shell:
$ vim --version

If you don't like the new Elflord, you can install the old Elflord from there in all its broken glory… or revert to the Vim version you had in your previous distro.
--- EDIT ---
The whole colorscheme remake was indeed part of the 9.0 release, which is what you have in Amazon Linux. See the paragraph above for a possible workaround.

The elford colorscheme is a standard colorscheme delivered with the Vim distribution. Each new version of Vim could comes with its own version of elford.
